# How do I remove the entire Media section from the main WordPress navigation without just hiding it?

Tags: media-library, admin-menu

I would like to remove the entire "Media" section from the main WordPress admin navigation ont he left hand side. What I don't want to do is just "hide" it with CSS or a plugin/function like I have done so below, because it's still accessible via the URL. This is crucial users shouldn't see each others uploads by any means.

Here's what I currently have, which just hides it. If you went to upload.php in the url, you could still access it.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_links' );
function remove_menu_links() {
    remove_menu_page('upload.php'); //remove media
}
```

Any ideas? A suitable method I believe would be to just direct the user to the dashboard with an error message if they tried to access the upload.php url? Not sure how to do this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indeed correct, before the admin update(i imagine the UI redesign, etc), unsetting items from the menus would in effect prevent access to those pages, that's clearly changed now and requires additional cap checking.

This isn't something i've looked into myself(as i've just found out this moment), so i can't speak about methods for doing so.. but it does bother me they've now turned a simple unsetting task into a bigger one that requires conditionalised capability checking(it's just more leg work that was not previously required).

## Moving on from the revelation:

Ok, seeing as the `remove_menu_page` and submenu equivalents are pretty much pointless now(i mean seriously, what good is making a page simply hidden from view) what i'd suggest is looping over the media submenu items and updating the required caps on the fly(if that's what you need to do).

This appears to have the desired outcome... :)

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_links' );
function remove_menu_links() {
    global $submenu;
    remove_menu_page('upload.php');
    foreach( $submenu['upload.php'] as $position => $data ) {
        $submenu['upload.php'][$position][1] = 'desired cap here';
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If you want the items completely gone / inaccessible, simply use a non-existant cap(or just leave the code as it is above)..

## Updated version of the above code:

Following on your last comment, perhaps it might be smart to do it like this... or something along these lines..

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_links' );
function remove_menu_links() {
    global $submenu;

    // Remove media for non-admins
    if( !current_user_can('manage_options') )
        remove_menu_page('upload.php');

    // Still need to update cap requirements even when hidden
    foreach( $submenu['upload.php'] as $position => $data ) {
        $submenu['upload.php'][$position][1] = 'manage_options';
    }
}
```

I realise now you do actually still need the `current_user_can` call, just to deal with conditionalising the removal of the parent item..

Comment: Hmm looks like a capability issue I'm having then. I have a custom wordpress role so looks like they might have a capability that is still allowing them to see the upload.php. I'll have another look, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Actually, I'm testing with admin now, and with the code above, I can still see the upload.php page while it's hidden. Should it be throwing an error message or something?

Comment: It says the following for `remove_menu_page` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

"Please be aware that this would not prevent a user from accessing these screens directly. Removing a menu does not replace the need to filter a user's permissions as appropriate."

Comment: No idea, can only speculate. I can say however, having worked with the menu array alot in the past, that unsetting items from the menu does prevent access to the given page(s) and does work across roles, if it doesn't work it's highly likely the result of code you're using, be it a plugin or whatever..

Comment: Correction, i tested incorrectly first time, seems the menu related code has changed... this never use to occur.. you were indeed correct.

Comment: I've added in some code that i believe will address the problem, lemme know if that helps.. ;)

Comment: Can't thank you enough :) Thanks for looking into this. I wish they left it how it used to be, but hey, at least it gets the job done. I've left the cap blank and wrapped the whole thing in a `if (!current_user_can('administrator')) { ... }` which should be perfect for my needs right now. Thanks again!

Comment: That's not really the way to do it, if you want it restricted to admins, update the blank space with an admin cap, ie. `manage_options`(remove the if condition you added). Also note `current_user_can` should never be passed a capability, it was never intended to accept one, and likely won't in future versions. All that said, happy i could help... ;)

Comment: Updated my answer with another example, you would actually need a `current_user_can` call still, just to deal with that parent item, the submenu items are the important ones here though, that's what sets the required cap above all else to view the given page(s).

Comment: Thanks, I went with your updated example above. The first one seemed to hide the media for the admin also. Are you sure about not passing roles through `current_user_can` ? Bit weird if the codex has many examples of it, but you aren't actually supposed to. I tend to rely on it heavily in some instances :)

Comment: It's possible the users who updated the codex pages in question were using the function incorrectly themselves. I can't recall the trac ticket specifically right now(it's referenced in other questions here though) but it certainly wasn't intended to take a role name, it's designed to accept a capability(or was at least last time i checked).

Answer (score 0):

Why not you try [Role scoper plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/)?

Comment: Thought role scoper was a bit overkill for my simple needs of removing that one menu